# loop over a python list

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a python list of Ids which I am calling in my function. There are around 200 ids. I would like to know what will be the best way to call these ids in chunks like I call 10 or 20 ids at a time and in next call, I call the next 20 ids and so on.. I have used multithreading here to make it faster but it seems to take lot of time. Here is the code I managed:

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
import numpy as np
import datetime as dt
df = pd.ExcelFile('ids.xlsx').parse('Sheet1')
x=[]
x.append(df['external_ids'].to_list())

def download():
    #client is my python sdk
    dtest_df = client.datapoints.retrieve_dataframe(external_id = x[0], start=0, end="now",granularity='1m')        
    dtest_df = dtest_df.rename(columns = {'index':'timestamp'})
    client.datapoints.insert_dataframe(dtest_df,external_id_headers = True,dropna = True)
    print(dtest_df)

with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=20) as executor:
    future = executor.submit(download)
    print(future.result())
```

Comment: "best" is opinion based.

Comment: Although in this case you have (probably?) profiled your code and see that it's too slow, ask about it instead.

Comment: Are you sure that the problem is not that your network connection cannot be faster?...

Comment: throw in more workers

Comment: cant have more workers as its is advised to have process in 5 multiple of your cores

Comment: Do you have a batch call API option?

Comment: @user202728 network is fine. I am more looking into how I can implement the looping as asked in my question

Comment: i dont know if there is a batch support.

Comment: I would still throw in more workers unless the CPU hits 90% plus

Comment: everything then the one asked in question is answered